# move files to usb drive using right click

Tags: usb

When I insert an USB drive, I want a right click menu (contextual menu) by which I will be able to copy / move files between harddisk and USB drive similar to the send to menu in windows. In Ubuntu 12.04, even though copy to and move to options are available, I do not find option to copy to or move to USB drive even though the drive is mounted. (I am able to copy/paste or cut/paste though it does not appeal to me as an elegant solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Nautilus, this [link](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Send+to...?content=67627) should help.

I have also found [this](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/send-to) Thunar.